# Redirection When user dont have the Right credentials

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard

I have 3 applications in my Symfony Project :

- one public app not secured
- and two other app are secured(**app1** & **app2**) with two diffrent credentials.

I'want when i'm connected on **app1** and i taped the url of **app2** insted of bolcking me and tell me that i don't have the right credentials redirect me to the **app1** that i'm connected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and took a look to the filter chain of symfony: [06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_filters).

If you are using security filter you might have to extend it or implement one on your own.

hope this helps.

Comment: do share some steps of the solution, it is likely to give a clearer picture to the less informed